# Enable one-click S3 file download without content-disposition header or access to metadata

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, download

I am looking to enable users to download files from S3 with one-click, from my site directly, without going to the destination URL and then right-clicking to finally download the original.

From what I understand, to do this in HTML I need to write `content disposition` header metadata to a file, before it's stored on S3, but I do not have access to S3 at the time of file generation.

Is there any way to force the browser to download a file in one-click anyway, without sending users to the s3 link to download it manually?

Comment: u could try, to get the content to ur server , n push the download in ur on url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems browser security prevents one-click download in any other way but with content header, as long as you have access to S3 there is a way to request a file with updated header using a `signed url` option.

In my case, for `Rails`, all it takes is an S3 gem, and an IAM user that has Get and Put permissions to your bucket.

Your IAM policy would look something like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET/*"
    }
]
```

}

Then, just

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(KEY, SECRET),
  region: REGION_CODE)
obj = s3.bucket(BUCKET).object(AWS_KEY)
obj.presigned_url(:get, response_content_disposition: 'attachment')
```

That will return a url that already the correct header, and it will auto-download in the browser.

Your syntax will differ based on language, but using S3 signed url should be somewhat similar in any language API.